# Why do I get a small window for confirmation of change of a password?

Tags: django

I have a class named CambiarPassword into views.py. This class change a password. It's working! But when I'm changing a password I am getting this windows.[image]

Here is my code into views.py file:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
class CambiarPassword(UpdateView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'app/edit_pass.html'
    success_url = '/index'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CambiarPassword, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = kwargs.pop('instance')
        return kwargs
```

How can I hide this window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not your code doing that, it's your browser. You probably use it to store passwords for some sites, and it tries to recognize change password forms. When you use a change password form, it updates the stored password.

Now your current site is "localhost", and you apparently have stored multiple accounts for that domain (like, from when you were working on different sites, or for completely different reasons). So it asks you for which account you are changing the password.

As many users rely on this feature, you probably shouldn't change your Django code so that Firefox doesn't recognize the change password form anymore.

If you just delete some locally stored passwords related to 'localhost', you won't get the window any more.